# convergence of sequence with log

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Any ideas to study the convergence of sequence u defined by
$$u_0,u_1>0,\quad \forall n\in \mathbb N, u_{n+2}=a\ln(1+u_n)+b\ln(1+u_{n+1})$$
with $a,b> 0$

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: I would certainly vote to close this question as stated. It has nothing to do with the difficulty of the mathematical question; rather, the question lacks context or discussion of the OP's thoughts. In other words, if the OP is convinced that it is an interesting and difficult question worthy of volunteers' time, they should include enough information in the post to persuade others of its interest and difficulty; the bare assertion is not sufficient.

Comment: In many cases, I would imagine that the sequence converges to the solution to $x=(a+b)\ln(1+x)$.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - how does the linked question fit in with this one?